# Reputation change when killing argon ships in Circle of Labor

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I am playing X3 Albion Prelude(Steam), I started game as Terran Commander, and from start reputation with argon is very low (Enemy of Federation), every ship is hosile to me.
Howewer where I destroyed argon ship in war sector (Circle of Labor), there was message "Argon federation thanks you for eliminating this thread". At this time i did not see reputation change in player info.

Question is: How reputation changes where you kill argon ship in Argon warzone? Is it possible to fix reputation with argon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you killed an Argon ship, no matter where on the map your reputation will reduce with the Argon. If you gained an acknowledgement then you probably killed a ship that is an enemy to the argon moving around in their sectors.

As for the reputation, try to find missions **given out** by Argonians. If it is too risky to move into Argon sectors or if their ports do not let you dock, then try a neighbouring sector which is not under direct argon control and try to find missions from an Argonian in one of the stations.

Note that the reputation increase is towards the race that handed you the mission, no matter which sector and which station you received it from. So you can improve your Argonian relations, just that you will have to work for it a bit in the beginning till they consider you to not be a threat and let you into their sectors and docks.

Comment: but why argon war fleet considered hostile to argon? :)

Comment: Are you sure it was Argonian ship? Maybe it was ATF. It could be an odd case where you defeated a wanted Argonian ship! There are too many possibilities. But be assured that what I have mentioned above is right.

Comment: yes, i am at rank "Guardian of Earth" and ATF is friendly to me. and that ship was Nova.